# ADF 12c and weblogic 11g

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have developed an application with adf 12c by jdeveloper 12c. But I have to deploy it on weblogic 11g. I looked for official guid but no success.
In oracle documents they said adf 12c supported by wls 10.3.5+, wls 12c. But is that means wls 11 supports 12c or not?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certification matrix http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/122-cert-2708091.html#ApplicationServers tells you that adf 12c is supported only for weblogic sever 12c. 
The answer to your question is no, wls 11g doesn't support ADF 12c applications.